How to change target framework for a unity project with UWP platform (I need it to implement ToastNotification)
I have a Unity project in UWP platform. I want to implement ToastNotification for it. As It have found in Microsoft Docs, I have to change the TFM to net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0 to be able to use All APIs(including Show()).
As I understood you can change the TFM through csproj, and it worked in my test visual studio project, but I can't find the related csproj for my unity project.
I'll appreciate any help regarding to this problem.

How exactly do you build your app from Unity? Do not directly build to an apk but rather build to a .sln solution, open it in VisualStudio and then build the final app package

Unity project only has NET 4.x and .NET Standard 2.1 are available.
Enabling the .NET 4.x scripting runtime in Unity
By default, the Api compatibility Level is set to .NET Standard. To change the .NET profile, go to Edit > Project Settings > Player >Other settings. Under the Configuration heading, set Api Compatibility Level to the desired setting.
